# Put result of an array with only one value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.8.

I have this in my controller where I limit only 1 result:

```
@photos = @shop.photos.find(:all, :limit => 1)
```

In my view, usually I just do a for loop to display the result:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag(photo.data.url(:preview)) %>
<% end %>
```

Now the above is for multiple values in an array. If I only have 1 value, must I continue using this method? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to store the result in an array.  The first parameter of [`find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) is whether you want to select `:all` record or just the `:first`.  You can store the only the first result in a variable `@photo`:

```
 @photo = @shop.photos.first
```

Then you can just display this one photo without looping:

```
 <%= image_tag(@photo.data.url(:preview)) %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will this be even better: `@photo = @shop.photos.first`?

Comment: Yeah for sure.  It'll be identical in function, just shorter syntax.

Comment: Between the array and this.  Or between first and find(:first)?  From Rails source `def first(*args); find(:first, *args); end` first() function just calls find(:first).  So, find(:first) is technically faster, but the difference is negligible compared to the time for database lookup, etc.